# How can I ROLLBACK psql -f command?

Tags: psql, rollback

I used this command.
`psql -U testuser -d testdb -f dump.sql`

And I want to know, if it is possible to rollback this command.

Contents of dump.sql are CREATE TABLE, few Inserts into that table and CREATE SEQUNCE, VIEW, DOMAIN.

please someone help me ;-(

Comment: No, but you can `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I edited contents of dump.sql. Is there a solution?

Comment: Yes. As I said, drop the created objects.